# Vuex: unregister module in `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook throws parent.getChild is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a simple component at the moment. There may be multiple instances existing at once.
Right now it looks like this:

```html
<template>
<v-row>
  <v-col>
    {{uid}}
  </v-col>
</v-row>
</template>
```

```js
import {module} from 'myModule.js'
// for unique ids
const uuidv4 = () => {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'test',
  components: {

  },
  computed: {
    uid() {
      return uuidv4()
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.$store.registerModule(`test-${this.uid}`, module)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    console.log(this.uid) // <--- logs correctly
    this.$store.unregisterModule(`test-${this.uid}`)
  }

}
```

When I unmount the component, I get

```
TypeError: "parent.getChild(...) is undefined"
unregister vuex.esm.js:217
    unregisterModule vuex.esm.js:506
    unregisterModule backend.js:907
    beforeDestroy test.vue:38
```

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: Sanity check: If you log `this.uid` twice in the beforeDestroy() hook, does it log the same value?

Comment: Looks like the error is being thrown in `vuex.esm.browser.js` line `211`. Can you try using the namespaced name for your module? If it's nested use that name. Since parent is being generated from line `209` which is using some fancy reduction to get children modules.

Comment: @Tanner yes it logs the same uid, although the state and getter of the register module are somehow different

Comment: @MikeHarrison I don’t quite follow. Wouldn’t that result in multiple instances of this component registering modules to the same place?

Comment: Namespaced modules is a vuex thing, which is where the error is coming from. The issue is not in your component. See [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) about namespacing your modules.

Comment: @MikeHarrison the module is namespaced (the property is set to true)

Comment: So instead of just using `test-${this.uid}` you would use `my_parent_name/test-${this.uid}`. Use the name of the file for `my_parent_name`

Comment: @MikeHarrison I don't see how that makes a difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202431/discussion-between-mike-harrison-and-sumneuron).